# How to Copy the text present in the dijit.Tooltip

Tags: html, tooltip, dojo

- On mouse over, am showing some text in the tool tip.
- On mouse click, i want to copy the text in the tool tip. is it possible to copy the text in the tool tip.

tool tip code:

```
 <img id="tooltipicon1" onclick="toolTipProperty('toolTipMain1')" src="images/tooltip_icon.gif" onmouseover="dijit.Tooltip.defaultPosition=['after','before']">
<div connectid="tooltipicon1" dojotype="dijit.Tooltip" id="toolTipMain1" label="">
<p style="width:250px;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut Tip With Caption enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution. It can be done using dijit/TooltipDialog

Html:

```
<div id="thenode">Move the mouse over me to pop up the dialog.</div>
```

Script:

```
     require([
    "dijit/TooltipDialog",
    "dijit/popup",
    "dojo/on",
    "dojo/dom",
    "dojo/domReady!"
    ], function(TooltipDialog, popup, on, dom){
    var myTooltipDialog = new TooltipDialog({
        id: 'myTooltipDialog',
        style: "width: 300px;",
        content: "<p>I have a mouse leave event handler that will close the dialog.",
        onMouseLeave: function(){
            popup.close(myTooltipDialog);
        }
    });

    on(dom.byId('thenode'), 'mouseover', function(){
        popup.open({
            popup: myTooltipDialog,
            around: dom.byId('thenode')
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: I don't see anything that has to do with "copying the text in the tooltip".

Comment: i didn't say about tool tip.. its tool tip dialog.. check the second example of the below link..  http://livedocs.dojotoolkit.org/dijit/TooltipDialog

Comment: I still don't see anything that has to do with "copying the text".